# How can you double space a file in C? Then print to STDOUT.

Tags: c, file

I need to read in a file, then print it out to STDOUT but double spaced. What I have so far is:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSZ 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

int n, fdin;
char buf[BUFSZ];

if ((fdin=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY))<0){
  perror(argv[1]);
  exit(-1);
}
while(( n = read(fdin, buf, BUFSZ))>0){
 if(write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,n) != n){
  fprintf(stderr, "Write Error\n");
  exit(-1);
 }
 printf("\n");
}
close(fdin);
return(0);
}
```

I'm new to C and don't know how I could implement the \n into the code, my printf("\n") is useless in trying to double space the entire file's contents. I think I have to add the \n into the read? But I'm not entirely sure if that's correct or how to do it.

Comment: By double space do you mean a blank line between each line read from the file?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need to do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) does not stop reading when it encounters a new-line character so the algorithm in the posted code could easily miss writing a blank line as the `read()` could read more than one line.

A simpler approach would use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets):

```
FILE* f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (f)
{
    char buf[BUFSZ];
    while (fgets(buf, BUFSZ, f))
    {
        printf("%s", buf);

        /* fgets() may not have read a full line if the
           length of the line was greater than BUFSZ,
           so check it did before double spacing. */
        if (strrchr(buf, '\n')) printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: This works great! But how could I avoid the very first blank line at the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 2):

The `open`, `close`, `read`, and `write` functions are specific to Unix (actually POSIX). The C language standard provides a higher-level set of functions (`fopen`, `fclose`, and a number of input and output functions), and there's no good reason not to use them here. Any system that has the POSIX-specific functions will have the standard C functions; the reverse is not necessarily true.

I'm not sure I should give you the code for a full solution (is this homework?), but I'll give you a quick outline.

There's no need to read and write full lines. This problem is easily solved by reading and writing just single characters -- and C's I/O functions do implicit buffering, so that won't cause any significant performance problem.

A "line" is simply a sequence of characters terminated by a newline `'\n'` character. (Don't worry about different end-of-line representations, like the `\r\n` used by Windows; if you open the file in text mode, the C library will take care of translating to and from C's internal `'\n'` representation.)

Read a character at a time from the input file. For each character you read, write that same character to your standard output. In addition, if the input character is `'\n'`, write a *second* `'\n'` to the standard output.

There are similar problems that would require reading an entire line at a time into memory (which means you need to worry about how long a line can be), but for this particular problem it's not necessary.

Comment: +1  By the way, the "homework" tag is being phased out. Not sure why.

Comment: @Dogbert: Yes, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Use fgets puts, and putc, it's much simpler and buffered.
And fgets read lines,

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE *fp;
    char *s;
    char buf[BUFSZ];
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening %s\n", argv[1] );
        exit(-1);
    }
    while((s = fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) != NULL){
        puts(s);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This fails (printing extra newlines) on input lines longer than `BUFSZ` characters.

Comment: @Keith right. Another even simpler solution is to use fgetc/putc , it is also buffered IIRC.